# jquery appending only one ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code that sends `ajax request` to `json-server` and sends request back that would be displayed into a `html div` using `jquery .html()`. The data displayed in that `div` would depend on the button the user `clicks`. Using `.append` appends well but just adds to the existing data displayed therefore showing data that is not in same category. Below is the code

**This should bring all in the category of software when clicked**

```
$(".software").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.music').removeClass('active');
    $('.fashion').removeClass('active');
    $('.business').removeClass('active');
    $('.life').removeClass('active');
    $('.digital').removeClass('active');
    $('.write').removeClass('active');
    var soft = 'Software Engineering';
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/users?category=${soft}`,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            $.each(res, function (idex, value) {

                usercat = "";
                usercat += `<div id="make-3D-space">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-card">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-front">`;
                usercat += `<div class="shadow"></div>`;
                usercat += `<img class="slateImg" src="${value.coverimage}" alt="" />`;
                usercat += `<div class="image_overlay">`;
                usercat += `<div class="product-options">`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i> </strong>${value.phonenumber}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-email"></i></strong>${value.email}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-newspaper"></i></strong>${value.description}</span>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats">`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats-container">`;
                usercat += `<span class="product_price">$${value.price}</span>`;
                usercat += `<a href="feeds.html?view=${value.username}"><span class="product_name">${value.username}</span></a>`;
                usercat += `<p>${value.category}</p>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;

                $("#featuredView").html(usercat);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**This should bring all in the category of fashion when clicked**

```
$('.fashion').click(function () {
    $(".featuredView").html();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.music').removeClass('active');
    $('.software').removeClass('active');
    $('.business').removeClass('active');
    $('.life').removeClass('active');
    $('.digital').removeClass('active');
    $('.write').removeClass('active');
    var fashion = 'Fashion';
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/users?category=${fashion}`,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            $.each(res, function (idex, value) {

                usercat = "";
                usercat += `<div id="make-3D-space">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-card">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-front">`;
                usercat += `<div class="shadow"></div>`;
                usercat += `<img class="slateImg" src="${value.coverimage}" alt="" />`;
                usercat += `<div class="image_overlay">`;
                usercat += `<div class="product-options">`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i> </strong>${value.phonenumber}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-email"></i></strong>${value.email}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-newspaper"></i></strong>${value.description}</span>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats">`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats-container">`;
                usercat += `<span class="product_price">$${value.price}</span>`;
                usercat += `<a href="feeds.html?view=${value.username}"><span class="product_name">${value.username}</span></a>`;
                usercat += `<p>${value.category}</p>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;

                $("#featuredView").html(usercat);
            });
        }
    });

});
```

The issue is say there is more than one data for fashion category in the database, only one is displayed when fashion is clicked. But if i use `.append()` all is displayed but using append, all data displays but when i click on software button, the data in software displays along side data in fashion that has already displayed.

I want that when i click on either button, all data in that particular category shows. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you using `.append()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear all the data before adding to `div`. Add this line after your `console.log`

`$("#featuredView").html('');`

Comment: That should not matter, they're using `$("#featuredView").html(usercat);` which effectively does the same as `$("#featuredView").html('');` and also writes to the div.

Comment: From the code you have up there, that shouldn't make a difference... Weird. Maybe they changed something on me. Well, at least it fixes your problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For your code above look fine but. should declare usercat outside loop and append to div outside loop too

```
$('.fashion').click(function () {
    $(".featuredView").html();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.music').removeClass('active');
    $('.software').removeClass('active');
    $('.business').removeClass('active');
    $('.life').removeClass('active');
    $('.digital').removeClass('active');
    $('.write').removeClass('active');
    var fashion = 'Fashion';
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: `http://localhost:3000/users?category=${fashion}`,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (res) {
            console.log(res);
            var usercat = "";
            $.each(res, function (idex, value) {


                usercat += `<div id="make-3D-space">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-card">`;
                usercat += `<div id="product-front">`;
                usercat += `<div class="shadow"></div>`;
                usercat += `<img class="slateImg" src="${value.coverimage}" alt="" />`;
                usercat += `<div class="image_overlay">`;
                usercat += `<div class="product-options">`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i> </strong>${value.phonenumber}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-email"></i></strong>${value.email}</span>`;
                usercat += `<span><strong><i class="mdi mdi-newspaper"></i></strong>${value.description}</span>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats">`;
                usercat += `<div class="stats-container">`;
                usercat += `<span class="product_price">$${value.price}</span>`;
                usercat += `<a href="feeds.html?view=${value.username}"><span class="product_name">${value.username}</span></a>`;
                usercat += `<p>${value.category}</p>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;
                usercat += `</div>`;

            });

            $("#featuredView").html(usercat);
        }
    });

});
```